# adding on change event listener inside a loop

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm making a map using leaflet.js in which I'm displaying list of countries from geojson file in a  tag when user selects a country it makes a fly effect and takes user to that country the function works fine if I use a dropdown with countries in  tag and use click event listener but when I use onchange event listener for select tag it first flies to the selected and country and then automatically starts flying to all the countries in the loop. I hope you understand the problem.

```
countryList.forEach((country) => {

      const option = document.createElement('option');
      
      //flying to the country on user click on country
      select.addEventListener('change', () => {
        
          flyToStore(country);
          
          
      });
      
      
      
      countries=country.properties.country;
      option.innerText =countries ;
     
      
      
      
  
     
      select.appendChild(option);
    });
    
  }
```

And here is the flytostore function that flies to country.

```
function flyToStore(store) {
    const lat = store.geometry.coordinates[1];
    const lng = store.geometry.coordinates[0];
    myMap.flyTo([lat, lng], 6, {
        duration: 3
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        L.popup({closeButton: false, offset: L.point(0, -8)})
        .setLatLng([lat, lng])
        .setContent(makePopupContent(store))
        .openOn(myMap);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: This happens because you are adding an addEventListener for every item in countryList, which makes no sense. You just need to define addEventListener once for the dropdown, outside the forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you should add your EventListener outside the forEach and add a value attribute to each Option refering to the country name as when you change the select value you are able to retrieve your country object in your countryList to pass it in the flyToStore function.

```
countryList.forEach((country) => {

     const option = document.createElement('option');
  
     option.innerText = country.properties.country ;
     option.value = country.properties.country ;

     select.appendChild(option);
});
//flying to the country on user click on country

select.addEventListener('change', () => {

     const selectedCountry = countryList.find( countryObj => 
                             countryObj.properties.country === select.value);

     flyToStore(selectedCountry);
   
});
```